# Programatically and Dynamically change ajax update property in jsf

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have an `AccordionPanel` created programatically inside which an `AJAX` event is defined (also programatically) now i want to change `UPDATE` property of ajax dynamically on tab change event defined in above `AJAX`.

i have tried to change using `myAjax.setUpdate(stringVariable)` using variable on ajax tab change event Method but this doesn't Work .
Component are Build using primeFaces Jar

**UPDATE**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="accordionForm">
           <h3>Change Event</h3>
    <p:accordionPanel id="saurabhpanel" multiple="true">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabbedView.onTabChange}" update="@this" />

         <p:tab  id ="tab1" title="saurabh" binding="#{tabbedView.tab}">

        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="tab2" title="sau" binding="#{tabbedView.tab2}">

        </p:tab>

    </p:accordionPanel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

This above code is working fine but when i create accordionpanel using java code and define ajax using code then on tab change it says component already exist **For my previous tab** i don't know why it try to update my previous open tab

Comment: did you try to set something like `update=#{managedBean.updatedId}`

Comment: i need to do it programatically in `java` class file not in `xhtml` file

Comment: and this what my method is doing making it programatically  from a `Java` Class

Comment: @YagamiLight please look to my update...